# Ampersand is not supporting in Appium driver.get method

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

In my test, we need to call an url scheme for a diagnostics purpose but the method is not supporting &.

`driver.get(abc-xx://qa-preview?adunit=banner)` it is working

`driver.get(abc-xx://qa-preview?adunit=banner&lat=10)` 
when I append & it is not working and throws the following message

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error attempting to start URI. Original error: Error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 83f0374b42535532 shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d abc-xx\://qa-preview\?adunit\=banner\&ctg\=2280352\&flt\=0\&nwk\=54 com.abc.droid.qa' exited with code 127'; Stderr: '/system/bin/sh: com.abc.droid.qa: not found'; Code: '127' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I have encoded the URL and tried it is passing through but that is not supported in my app. In our app only normal URL is supported for scheme. Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Comment: Have you read the error line completely?  It doesn't match your reported problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String url = "Your URL Containing &";
    String url1 = url.trim();
    String url2 = url1.replace(/&/g,"-");
```

Comment: I don't want to replace &. Is there a way that the URL works with &

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.